# pull 500 post of many from database

Tags: loop

I'm using the premium theme, which is using

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

this code to pull post from database but it pulled all the post from **and i want some specific number let say 500**. I googled and didn't find any filter which gives limit features.

**Note:** i have to use only above function to fetch data. So anyone could please help me on this?

Comment: <?php if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> this is the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function posts_limits_set( $limit, $query ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) { 
        return 'LIMIT 0, 100';
    } 

    return $limit;
}
add_filter( 'post_limits', 'posts_limits_set', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: but it's not working. Could you please try on your end?

Comment: it's working for me.

Comment: I just put your code in functions.php file and check on category page, using that <?php if ( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>  code and nothing changed. still this code getting all the records.

Comment: you can set the limit in settings > readings "Blog pages show at most"

Comment: Yes it set to 10 and i have on the localhost 22 records and still all the records pulled from the database.

Comment: function custom_posts_per_page($query) {
      
        if (is_archive()) {
            $query->set('posts_per_page', 10);
        } 
    }   
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page');

Comment: Please paste above code on funcation.php file

Comment: Above code is working and make 10 post per page but top above code is not working. Still all the results(22) pulled from database

Comment: so use this only 
function custom_posts_per_page($query) { if (is_archive()) { $query->set('posts_per_page', 10); } } add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page');

Comment: But this is not the solution, i don't want per page solution. I want to pulled specific number out of all results and after that want to show that using the pagination. pagination thing i did already.

Comment: ok please check this code function posts_limits_set( $limit, $query ) {
        return 'LIMIT 0, 100';
    return $limit; }
add_filter( 'post_limits', 'posts_limits_set', 10, 2 );

Comment: This code also not working, still got the all results on category page.

Comment: You changed the limit on that code please make it 10 then check

Comment: i already did but this code only make 10 results per page. This code is not belongs to pull specific number of data out of all.

Comment: Ok then final code is <?php if ( have_posts() ) :
           $i = 1;       while ( have_posts() && $i < 10) : the_post(); 
     $i++; endwhile; ?> please use it

Comment: Doing the above thing only reduce the loop cycle but this query load all the results.